# What's causing this error in a subclass of MKAnnotationView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, compiler-errors, mapkit

I'm trying to create a subclass of MKAnnotationView for an iPhone Mapkit app, but for some reason I am suddenly encountering this error:

`Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1`

These are my header and main files for the code that seems to be causing the error. Though the error does not show up for this file specifically, it does not appear if I comment out the .m file from @implementation to @end. It does still appear if I comment everything in the implementation not including the @implementation itself, however.

**PhotoAnnotationView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface PhotoAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView { 
    UIImageView *thumb; 
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *thumb;

@end
```

**PhotoAnnotationView.m**

```
#import "PhotoAnnotationView.h"


@implementation PhotoAnnotationView

@synthesize thumb;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

This is basically the same code that Xcode created via `New File... > Objective-C Class > Subclass of: UIView` with the subclass changed.

I'm on Snow Leopard running version 3.2.1 of Xcode.

Comment: Should I try reinstalling Xcode? I don't see any good reason why I should be getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you link your application with MapKit.framework? The compiler may not know about MKAnnotationView cs and therefore output this error.

To add the framework to your project go to Target settings in one of the menus of Xcode (I don't have Xcode here at hand, unfortunately) and on the first tab click the plus button and select MapKit.framework from the list.

I hope that'll help.

Comment: My project references CFNetwork, CoreLocation, MapKit, UIKit, Foundation, and CoreGraphics. Also I have been able to use MapKit features before now.